# Angular routing adding random scrollbars

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm currently having this issue with angular after I hooked up my components to routing where scroll bars would appear all over my page and scrolling would be really buggy. My components worked fine until I added routing. In one of my pages, the page scrolls but the content would not display. It's sort of hard to explain but I've included a screenshot. In another component that has a max-height of 100vh, it added a scroll bar and if I scroll down I would see parts of another component.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What does the HTML and CSS look like?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, it was a rather simple fix. My editor for some reason had a component hidden so on my app.component I had a component for one of my pages with router-outlet. I just had to remove the page component to fix the issue.